# fragment arguments are null using launchFragmentInContainer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-safe-args, android-fragmentscenario

I am writing a test for a fragment that uses `safeArgs` and `FragmentScenario`, however when I call `launchFragmentInContainer()` with the `fragmentArgs` parameter, I get an exception saying the arguments are null. There is no problem in production code.

My navigation graph:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentNewListItems"
        android:name="com.hotmail.or_dvir.arislistkt2.vvm.FragmentNewListItems"
        android:label="@string/title_newItems"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_list_items">

        <argument
            android:name="listId"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="listName"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
```

My test:

```
class TesFragmentNewListItems : BaseAndroidTest() {
    private lateinit var fragScenario: FragmentScenario<FragmentNewListItems>

    private val list1 = UserList("list 1")

    @Before
    fun before() {
        //adding a user list to add items to
        repoUserLists.addLists(list1)
        fragScenario = this.launchFragment(
            //setting arguments here
            bundleOf("listId" to list1.id, "listName" to list1.name)
        )
    }


    inline fun <reified T : Fragment> launchFragment(args: Bundle): FragmentScenario<T> {
        return launchFragmentInContainer<T>(
            themeResId = R.style.AppTheme,
            fragmentArgs = args
        )
    }
```

when i try to run the test i get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument "listId" is marked as non-null but was passed a null value.
```

full stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.runOnMainSync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:441)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.onActivity(ActivityScenario.java:564)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.internalLaunch(FragmentScenario.java:300)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.java:282)
at com.hotmail.or_dvir.arislistkt2.TesFragmentNewListItems.before(TesFragmentNewListItems.kt:79)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:76)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.koin.test.mock.MockProviderRule$apply$1.evaluate(MockProviderRule.kt:13)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy.getValue(NavArgsLazy.kt:52)
at androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy.getValue(NavArgsLazy.kt:34)
at com.hotmail.or_dvir.arislistkt2.vvm.FragmentNewListItems.getFragArgs(Unknown Source:4)
at com.hotmail.or_dvir.arislistkt2.vvm.FragmentNewListItems.onViewCreated(FragmentNewListItems.kt:31)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:332)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1199)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2181)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2004)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1959)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1830)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:297)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:317)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:301)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.lambda$onActivity$2$ActivityScenario(ActivityScenario.java:551)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source:4)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:2207)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument "listId" is marked as non-null but was passed a null value.
at com.hotmail.or_dvir.arislistkt2.vvm.FragmentNewListItemsArgs$Companion.fromBundle(FragmentNewListItemsArgs.kt:28)
at com.hotmail.or_dvir.arislistkt2.vvm.FragmentNewListItemsArgs.fromBundle(Unknown Source:2)
... 30 more
```

### Edit:

The id of `List1` is not null as it is initialized in the constructor.

```
class UserList(
    name: String
) : BaseItem(name) {

    //class body
}
```

```
abstract class BaseItem(
    var name: String,
    var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
) {

    //class body
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out. i somehow missed this warning:

```
W/Bundle: Key listId expected String but value was a java.util.UUID.  The default value <null> was returned.
```

all i had to do was change this `bundleOf("listId" to list1.id...)` to `bundleOf("listId" to list1.id.toString()...)` (added call to `toString()`)

not sure why google chose to handle invalid types by turning them into `null` instead of throwing an "InvalidParameter" exception (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

From your post it is not clear, what the `UserList` and `repoUserLists` classes looks like. How is `id` initialized? You only seem to pass a parameter for the `name` to the `UserList` constructor. Does `repoUserLists` do the initialization of the `id`?

My assumption would be that `id` is in fact `null`, as the exception message states.

Do you  have some initialization of the `id` that only works for production builds, not in the test environment?

To verify this you should add a line to your `before` method after line

```kotlin
repoUserLists.addLists(list1)
```

that verifies `list1.id` is actually not `null`.

Comment: edited the question. `id` is initialized in the constructor.